# Get the Duration an Outlook Email was Composed for

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, office365api, office365-restapi

I've looked at the **Message** (email) class in the [Office 365 API Resource Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#message), as well as the other classes and various Office 365 docs, but there doesn't seem to be an elegant method for obtaining the duration a user spent composing an email. I'm very surprised that the **Message** class does not have a "ComposedTime" attribute or something along those lines, for emails in the **SentItems** (Sent) folder.

My current implementation is very brute-force, I am hoping there is a more straightforward implementation, thank you!

Comment: I'd be surprised if it **did** have such a statistic - why would it? It doesn't seem very useful... Are you tracking how long the email is open? What about when I go for lunch & leave the email open & unfinished? What about time when it's in the "drafts" folder? Seems like a lot of work to collect a piece of data which is likely to be pretty inaccurate anyway.

Comment: @Kryten Those are valid points, but they already handle those cases: from my empirical evidence the Outlook Web Portal is running a timer in the background that checks every minute whether or not the draft was changed in that period, so they already have a pretty accurate number. It could be very very useful for many applications. I am not tracking how long the email is open, just how long they spent editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back end doesn't track that, so no, there is no property for it. You can always suggest it on [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks, will do! Also, how would you do it brute-force, using the existing properties?

Comment: I don't think you really can with any confidence. There's a timestamp for when a message was created and when it was last modified, but that's it. Created should tell you the first time it was actually saved (could have been open in a new mail window for who knows how long before that). Last modified doesn't necessarily mean the user was done composing.